# cpytoimpf with STMFCODPAG(*PCASCII) creates a file in IFS with 949 ccsid

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am using CPYTOIMPF with STMFCODPAG(*PCASCII), the resultant file in IFS folder is getting created with 949 CCSID. How 949 ccsid has come into picture?

Comment: Now that is weird. I can only suggest that you have some data in the source table that is being interpreted as Korean (what happens if you hard code the target CCSID to the one you were /expecting/ to find?) The only other comment I'd make is that the IBM documentation says STMFCODPAG is deprecated & you should be using STMFCCSID. I'd be inclined to try with that, just in case.

Comment: what's the CCSID of the character fields in the table (PF)?

Comment: You are right MandyShaw. I was trying to generate IFS file which contains Korean characters. I now hard coded in the program with STMFCCSID(1208). It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to generate file in IFS which contains Korean characters from the profile with Korean CCSID (933). I used CPYTOIMPF with STMFCODPAG(*PCASCII). This created junk characters in resultant IFS file. I hard coded in the program with STMFCCSID(1208). This removed the unsupported characters without creating any junk characters.